# Grapheme support in python regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode, grapheme

I'm using the awesome [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, trying its `\X` grapheme support.

First, I try with the plain old `.`

```
>>> print regex.match('.', 'Ä').group(0)

>>> print regex.match('..', 'Ä').group(0)
Ä
```

It went as expected. Move on to `\X`

```
>>> print regex.match('\X', 'Ä').group(0)

>>> print regex.match('\X\X', 'Ä').group(0)
Ä
```

Why is it the same as `.`? Shouldn't a single `\X` be enough to capture the A-umlaut? Is it:

- My understanding of grapheme or the meaning of `\X` is wrong?
- Some flag/switch I need to turn on first? (I've searched the documentation, couldn't find)
- Something with my environment? (Python 2.7.3, pip reports regex==2014.12.24)
- Bug in the library?
- Something else?

Comment: i think the problem is only with the 2.7 version. In 3.4 `print(regex.match('\X', 'Ä').group(0))` prints the letter `Ä`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works by defining the `Ä` as unicode character.

```
>>> print regex.match('.', u'Ä').group()
Ä
>>> print regex.match('\X', u'Ä').group()
Ä
```

The main difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is the basic types that exist to deal with texts and bytes. On Python 3 we have one text type: `str` which holds Unicode data and two byte types bytes and bytearray.

On the other hand on Python 2 we have two text types: `str` which for all intents and purposes is limited to ASCII + some undefined data above the 7 bit range, unicode which is equivalent to the Python 3 str type and one byte type bytearray which it inherited from Python 3.

Reference - https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that by default python2 string are byte strings which makes no sense with unicode grapheme. If you specify using unicode strings it perfecly work.

```
>>> print(regex.match('\X', 'Ä').group(0))

>>> print(regex.match('\X', u'Ä').group(0))
Ä
```

In python3 the default string is unicode and to specify byte string you should prepend a `b` like this `b"mybytestring"`